# Month Difference between rows by group in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have data that looks like this using PostgreSQL

```
customer name       order_id         order_date
John                A001             1-Jan-2017
John                A002             1-Feb-2017
John                A003             1-Apr-2017
Smith               A004             1-Dec-2016
Smith               A005             1-Feb-2017
Jane                A006             1-Mar-2017
Dave                A007             1-Feb-2017
Dave                A008             1-Feb-2017
Dave                A009             1-Feb-2017
```

I'm trying to get the difference between month of repurchases in another column. So something like this.

```
customer name       order_id         order_date        month_diff
John                A001             1-Jan-2017        null
John                A002             1-Feb-2017        1
John                A003             1-Apr-2017        2
Smith               A004             1-Dec-2016        null
Smith               A005             1-Feb-2017        3
Jane                A006             1-Mar-2017        null
Dave                A007             1-Feb-2017        null
Dave                A008             1-Feb-2017        0
Dave                A009             1-Feb-2017        0
```

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciation. I'm new to postgreSQL. Thank you in advance

Comment: What is `order_date` column type ?

Comment: plase put data set with obvious delimiter or better use http://rextester.com or so to build schema

Comment: it's a timestamp

Answer (score 2):

This can easily be done  using window functions (assuming that `order_date` is properly defined as `DATE`)

```
select customer_name,
       order_id, 
       order_date, 
       order_date - lag(order_date) over (partition by customer_name order by order_date) as diff
from order_table
order by customer_name, order_date;
```

Note that the result of the diff is in days if `order_date` is a `date`.

Comment: If it is always first day of the month then he can get month diff like this: `select extract('month' from age(to_date('1-Apr-2017', 'D-Mon-YYYY'), to_date('1-Dec-2016', 'D-Mon-YYYY')))`

Answer (score 0):

[try with](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html) `first_value()`:

```
select 
customer_name, order_id, order_date
, order_date - first_value(order_date) over (partition by customer_name order by order_id) as month_diff
from tname;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select
t.customer,
t.order_id,
t.order_date,
(select extract(MONTH from t.order_date) - extract(MONTH from tt.order_date) 
    from your_table tt
    where tt.order_id < t.order_id
    order by tt.order_id desc limit 1
)
from your_table t
order by t.order_id
```